# iOS alarm clock, keep alarm sound playing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio

I am creating an alarm clock app that continuously plays the sound I have set. Right now, when I click the notification when the alarm goes off, the alarm stops and the app opens. 
Is there a way to open the app, but keep the sound playing when I click the notification?

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.alertBody  =@"Wake up!";
    notification.soundName = @"sax.mp3";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

    [notification release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just let the alarm go off, but play the same music again. I mean after the alarm stops - your music stops,too. But then you run the same music again when the application opens